# Branching process probability generating function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to solve the following exercise but I can't seem to solve it.

> A branching process $(X_n :n \geq 0)$ has $P(X_0 = 1) = 1$. Let the total number of individuals in the first $n$ generations of the process $Z_n$, with probability generating function $Q_n$. Prove that for $n \geq 2$
>
> $$ Q_n(s) = sP_1(Q_{n-1}(s))$$
> with $P_1$ is the probability generating function $Q_n$ of the family-size distribution.

What I immediately understood, was that we have to relate $Z_n$, the number of individuals in the first $n$ generations, to $Z_{n-1}$, which is the number of individuals in the first $n-1$ generations. Logically: $Z_n = Z_{n-1} + C$ , where we call $C$ the number of individuals in the $n$'th generation. Note that $Z_{n-1}$ and $C$ are independent.

$$Q_n(s) = E(s^{Z_n}) = E(s^{Z_{n-1}+C}) = E(s^{Z_{n-1}})E(C) = Q_{n-1}(s)E(C)$$.

I believe this is not what I should be doing, does anyone have any hints on how to attack this problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: To be hones I don't understand the sentence "with P1 is the probability generating function Qn of the family-size distribution". Could you write a more formal definition?

Comment: If $X_n$ is the [Galton–Watson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process) with $X_{n+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{X_n}\xi_j^{(n)}$ and $\xi_j^{(n)}$ i.i.d.; $Z_n:=\sum_{i=0}^n X_i$; $Q_n(s):=E\left[s^{Z_n}\right]$; and $P_1(s):=E\left[s^{\xi}\right]$, then the relationship $Q_n(s)=s P_1(Q_{n-1}(s))$ makes no sense. This relationship is telling us, in words, that the individuals at generation $n$ are not only descendant from individuals at generation $n-1$, but also from all individuals $Z_{n-1}$ comprising all previous generations.

Comment: More formally, under the assumption that your process $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is rather defined as $X_{n+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{Z_{n}}\xi_j^{(n)}$, then the relation holds. Please, define the processes in your question and/or point to a reference.